# QtQuick Dynamic object problems with javascript dictionarys

Tags: javascript, qml, qtquick2

Whats happeneing here is probably a logic error but ive been rewriting this function for the better part of an hour and I cant find it, theres not another function somewhere else rewriting these values and messing it up. i should also note here that the elements are appearing on screen just over the previous elements. What the function is supposed to do is to replace all the elements after one another using the data from the dictionary as text in the ui elements

Here is a gif of the issue im having in action https://gyazo.com/89628e6d303fc36f0a3c85f6336e03f7
as far as i can tell this is the function that is at fault here, listItems is the large white box and listitems.children[x] is the child in question.

```
function populateTable(){
    background.total = 0
    var num = parseInt(background.total);
    var component = Qt.createComponent("Listitem.qml");
    for(var key in background.dictionary) {
        cba.text = key
        console.log(num + "num")
        var sprite = component.createObject(listItems, {"x": (listItems.width / 32 * .5)-1, "y": (listItems.height / 32 * (2.5*parseInt(background.total)))-1+(listItems.height/32)*.68, "ident": parseInt(background.total)});
        console.log(background.total + " pos, function populateTable")
        listItems.children[num].children[1].text = cba.text + ": " + search(cba.text)
        num = num+1
    }
    console.log("Opperation Completed")
}
```

if someone could tell me where im messing up that would be great, thanks in advance for any help

main.js:

```
function declareDict(){
    console.log("Creating Blank Dictionary")
    var dict = {};
    return dict;
}

function add(thing1, thing2){
    background.dictionary[thing1] = thing2;
    txtName.text = ""
    txtAddress.text = ""
}

function search(term){
    var temp = background.dictionary[term];
    console.log(temp + " function search")
    return temp;
}

function deleteAll(){
    btnDelConf.visible = true
}

function removeAll(){
    return declareDict();
}

function remove(term){
    delete background.dictionary[term];
}

function processRemove(element){
    background.pos = parseInt(background.pos)-1
    listItems.children[element].destroy()
}

function populateTable(){
    var num = 0;
    var component = Qt.createComponent("Listitem.qml");
    for(var key in background.dictionary) {
        var sprite = component.createObject(listItems, {"x": (listItems.width / 32), "y": (listItems.height / 32 * (2.5*parseInt(num)))+(listItems.height/32), "ident": parseInt(num)});
        num = num+1
    }
    console.log("Opperation Completed")
}
```

Listitem.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "main.js" as JS
Rectangle {
    property int ident
    ident: index
    id: listItem
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: parent.width / 32 * 30
    height: parent.height / 16
    color: "#000000"
    Rectangle {
        id: btnRemove
        x: parent.width / 16 * 14
        y: 0
        width: parent.width / 16 * 2
        height: parent.height
        color: "#000000"
        border.color: "#ffffff"

        MouseArea {
            id: msAreaRemove
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            onClicked: {
                parent.parent.destroy()

            }
        }

        Text {
            id: txtRemove
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Del")
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: dispListItem
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: parent.width / 16 * 14
        height: parent.height
        color: "#ffffff"
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "main.js" as JS



Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Super important thing")
    Rectangle {
        id: background
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        x: 0
        y: 0
        color: "#555555"
        property int total: 0
        property var dictionary: JS.declareDict()
        TextInput {
            id: cba
            x: -10
            y: -10
            width: 0
            height: 0
            font.weight: Font.Normal
            text: ""
            echoMode: TextInput.Normal
        }

        Text {
            id: lblAddress
            x: parent.width / 32 * 17
            y: parent.height / 32 * 12
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#888888"
            text: qsTr("Address: ")
            font.pixelSize: height * .8
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        }

        Text {
            id: lblName
            x: parent.width / 32 * 17
            y: parent.height / 32 * 8
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#888888"
            text: qsTr("Name: ")
            font.pixelSize: height * .8
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        }

        Text {
            id: lblAddEntry
            x: parent.width / 32 * 24 - width / 2
            y: parent.height / 32 * 6
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#888888"
            text: qsTr("Add Entry:")
            font.pixelSize: height / 2
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }

        Text {
            id: lblEditAddressBook
            x: parent.width / 32 * 24 - width / 2
            y: parent.height / 32 * 3
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#888888"
            text: qsTr("Edit Address Book Details")
            font.pixelSize: height * .75
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: listItems
            x: parent.width / 32
            y: parent.height / 32 * 3
            width: parent.width / 32 * 15
            height: parent.height / 32 * 24
            color: "#ffffff"
        }

        Text {
            id: text1
            x: parent.width / 32
            y: parent.height / 32
            width: parent.width / 32 * 30
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("My Address Book")
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: btnAdd
            x: parent.width / 32 * 27
            y: parent.height / 32 * 10
            width: parent.width / 16 * 2
            height: parent.height / 32 * 6
            color: "#000000"
            border.color: "#000000"

            MouseArea {
                id: msAreaAdd
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                onClicked: {
                    JS.add(txtName.text, txtAddress.text)
                    JS.populateTable()
                }
                KeyNavigation.tab: txtNameSearch
                KeyNavigation.backtab: txtAddress
            }

            Text {
                id: txtAddBtn
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                color: "#ffffff"
                text: qsTr("Add")
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: boxName
            x: parent.width / 32 * 17
            y: parent.height / 32 * 10
            width: parent.width / 32 * 10
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#ffffff"
            border.color: "#007700"
            TextInput {
                id: txtName
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                maximumLength: 24
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.weight: Font.Normal
                text: ""
                KeyNavigation.tab: txtAddress
                KeyNavigation.backtab: msAreaSearch
                echoMode: TextInput.Normal
                font.pixelSize: height / 8 * 6
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: boxAddress
            x: parent.width / 32 * 17
            y: parent.height / 32 * 14
            width: parent.width / 32 * 10
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#ffffff"
            border.color: "#007700"
            TextInput {
                id: txtAddress
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                maximumLength: 24
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.weight: Font.Normal
                text: ""
                KeyNavigation.tab: msAreaAdd
                KeyNavigation.backtab: txtName
                echoMode: TextInput.Normal
                font.pixelSize: height / 8 * 6
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: boxNameSearch
            x: parent.width / 32
            y: parent.height / 32 * 28
            width: parent.width / 32 * 11
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#ffffff"
            border.color: "#007700"
            TextInput {
                id: txtNameSearch
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                maximumLength: txtName.maximumLength
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.weight: Font.Normal
                text: ""
                KeyNavigation.tab: msAreaSearch
                KeyNavigation.backtab: msAreaAdd
                echoMode: TextInput.Normal
                font.pixelSize: height / 8 * 6
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: btnSearch
            x: parent.width / 32 * 12
            y: parent.height / 32 * 28
            width: parent.width / 16 * 2
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#000000"
            border.color: "#000000"

            MouseArea {
                id: msAreaSearch
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                onClicked: {
                    JS.search(txtNameSearch.text)
                    txtNameSearch.text = ""
                }
                KeyNavigation.tab: txtName
                KeyNavigation.backtab: txtNameSearch
            }

            Text {
                id: txtSearchBtn
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                color: "#ffffff"
                text: qsTr("Search")
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: btnDelAll
            x: parent.width / 32 * 17
            y: parent.height / 32 * 28
            width: parent.width / 32 * 14
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#000000"
            border.color: "#ff0000"

            MouseArea {
                id: msAreaDelAll
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                onClicked: {
                    JS.deleteAll()
                }
            }

            Text {
                id: txtDelAllBtn
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                color: "#ffffff"
                text: qsTr("Delete All")
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: btnDelConf
            x: parent.width / 32 * 17
            y: parent.height / 32 * 28
            width: parent.width / 32 * 14
            height: parent.height / 32 * 2
            color: "#ff0000"
            border.color: "#ff6600"
            visible: false

            MouseArea {
                id: msAreaDelConf
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                onClicked: {
                    background.dictionary = JS.removeAll()
                    btnDelConf.visible = false
                }
            }

            Text {
                id: txtDelAllConf
                x: 0
                y: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                color: "#000000"
                text: qsTr("Clicking Again Will Delete Everything")
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.pixelSize: 12
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a dropbox link to the project: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ky95ttlfmf5qhwl/DataStructuresAssessment4Version3.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ive attached my project file for your perusal

Comment: You should provide minimal working example if you want to get right answer here. No external links

Comment: Now ive added the code to the post

Comment: **Too much code.** You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need to **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck, provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil)**.